# Decomposition of **3D** structuring elements for morphological operations

Tags: 3d, morphological-operations, decomposition

I am struggling to implement a mathematical morphology toolset in an image processing package. I base my implementation on what I saw in MATLAB, and on several papers on the subject.

There seems to be abundant literature on morphological operation optimization through structuring element (strel) decomposition. For instance, one can get a tremendous speed bonus by using two orthogonal lines instead of a square as structuring element for dilation. Several papers give methods for optimization through strel decomposition:

1. Rolf Adams, "Radial Decomposition of Discs and Spheres," CVGIP:
            Graphical Models and Image Processing, vol. 55, no. 5, September
            1993, pp. 325-332.
2. Rein van den Boomgard and Richard van Balen, Methods for
          Fast Morphological Image Transforms Using Bitmapped Binary
          Images, CVGIP: Models and Image Processing, vol. 54, no. 3, May
          1992, pp. 252-254

etc...

However, all these publications are about **2D** structuring elements. I could not find much on **3D** decompositions.

Do you have any clues on how to decompose:

1. a 3D sphere. Not a ball that is used in 2D grayscale morphology, but an actual flat 3D sphere;
2. a 3D diamond?

Comment: Can you explain why the flat 2D sphere (AKA circle) approach cannot be generalized to a flat 3D sphere?

Comment: @PeterK.: I actually don't know. Yet. I just did experiments on the diamond decomposition and saw it does not generalize. The papers explicitly only treat the 2D case.

Comment: Did you manage to implement a sphere decomposition? (maybe even in Matlab?)
Thanks for your response!

Comment: @DarkCell : please do NOT post comments as answers. Please DO answer questions and get enough rep to post comments. Please do NOT ask people for their personal identifying information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this depends on the digital distance transform that one is approximating on the 3d grid and there are various local connectivities [possible](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S107731429690065X). There is an implementation in ImageJ [here](http://fiji.sc/Distance_Transform_3D).

It would also be good to verify if you are using a non-flat structuring element or a correct 3d structuring element. Read [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98729) reference here. In the place of euclidean distance *sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2)* one could add the Manhattan distance using [this](http://heuristicswiki.wikispaces.com/3D+Manhattan+distance). Quick 3d distance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693514/very-fast-3d-distance-check).

For 3d structuring element decomposition one can [see](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11556121_79). But the 3d decompositions of a convex shapes like sphere into separable 2d lines is non-trivial, certain shapes are easier than others like the cube. One can refer [here](http://ismm.dpi.inpe.br/col/dpi.inpe.br/ismm@80/2007/03.20.04.48/doc/ISMM2007fullpaper/fullpaper.pdf) for efficient algorithms for spheres.

Comment: Hi. I am thinking of a proper flat 3D structuring element. Thanks, I had no clue that changing the distance transform could help simplify the problem.

Comment: Hey Jean, The comment is for flat 3d structuring element, if its non flat - it would become 4d - in the sense, you would have numerical weights for each element in the structuring function - and you would use the Minkowski addition to determine the result of the operation. 

Also the distance function basically determines what connectivity we are using. If one can express this locally in windows of 3x3 or 5x5 or in 3d windows, one can obtain different forms like Manhattan distance, the disk etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the paper by Vaz et al. about the decomposition of a 3D flat sphere. It is efficient and clever. 
However, I could not find an implementation anywhere that would help me to get started. Would you have some leads there?

Comment: Jean-Yeves: I will can give you code if you are still interested (you can connect with me via Linkedin). Best, Michael Vaz

Comment: @MichaelVaz: Thanks! But there are too many homonyms on LinkedIn to find you. Would you care to post the code on a public repository?